How to address past academic misconduct as a new faculty member?
14 years ago, as an undergraduate student in a country with limited academic resources, I was eager to apply for a master's degree abroad. I visited a lab at my university where, despite my lack of research experience, a professor kindly added me as the third author on his paper to support my graduate school application. Then, starting from the foreign graduate school, I met my PhD supervisor and pursued a research field different from this work, completing my PhD and two postdoc positions. I am now residing abroad and an incoming assistant professor at a prestigious worldwide university.
Recently, while reflecting on my past work, I discovered that this paper was essentially an extension of the professor's previous work with minimal changes but lacking proper citations. He submitted the same paper with minimal changes to different journals, using different author names each time. This is a clear case of self-plagiarism. The paper was published in the journal held by my university in my native language, likely read only by university staff, and the institution ranks beyond 5000+ globally. At the time, I did not notice these issues as I had limited academic knowledge, including the inability to conduct proper literature searches and fully understand the paper.
As a supervisor now advising students and advocating for the highest standards of academic integrity, I feel guilty about this past misconduct. In my home country, such issues were often overlooked, and at the time, I naively viewed academic activity as merely a game of adding names to papers.
While it is unlikely that anyone will notice this paper due to its limited impact, I am struggling with how to reconcile my past actions with my current role and teachings. I want to continue educating my students to be honest researchers, as I have strived to be over the past fourteen years. However, how should I address this situation, both personally and professionally, as I begin my faculty position? Contacting the journal editor or the professor may prove futile, as they are unlikely to view this as a significant issue given the academic culture in my home country.

I suggest that you let the past be the past and just let it go. You seem to have moved beyond where you were years ago, and as an undergraduate, no less. Any fault in that episode is primarily that of your old professor.
We were all young and naive once. We've all made mistakes of one kind or another. Hopefully we learn from those mistakes and move on.
If you do ever get called, admit to the error and point out that you've learned from that. You can even use it as an object lesson for things not to do. But there is no reason for you to bring it up initially. Again, let it go.

I would add to this that the OP should probably take this paper off documents like their CV or other lists of publications, if they wouldn't stand by it now. (Although I suspect they already have done so.)

I never included this paper in my CV before, as it's completely unrelated to my main research field. Recently, however, I've been aiming to make my CV more comprehensive to showcase my research trajectory. As a result, I've dug up this paper and plan to add it to my CV. And then I found this problem.

@whoami I would strongly advise against adding that paper. Your CV is meant to show your work,and from your description it sounds like this paper contains very little if any original work of yours. It can probably do more harm than good.

@Buffy Did you mean abject lesson?

@MiniRagnarok, no. "Object lesson". An American idiom. An important lesson that can be generalized.

@Buffy Fair enough. Googling was giving me both and I was having a hard time figuring out how their definitions applied. It seems like object lessons were popular around the Victorian era.

There are things about your life you can't change in retrospect -- I assume that, like all of us, there are other parts of your past you are not proud of.
What matters is what you make of it. It seems like you've learned from it -- you understand the ethical dimensions of it, and that allows you to incorporate the mistake of back then into how you teach and mentor others: You can use it as an example for others to learn from. I don't think anyone is going to think less of you for something that was clearly outside your realm of experience that long ago.
I would like to also point out one other aspect: Your adviser at the time showed great kindness to you in adding you to the paper. Perhaps that was questionable as far as publication ethics are concerned, but they understood that you had potential and could use a leg up in making your dream possible. In my own life, I carry a rather small (metaphorical) bag of negative experiences around with me, but a rather large one in which I keep and treasure the kindness I have experienced from mentors and colleagues who did more than they needed to to help me in my career. Now that I'm in mid-career, it is my time to show the same kind of kindness to those around me. Do the same, your adviser was actively being helpful to someone who he did not need to be helpful to, and acted within the realm of his abilities (however limited and questionable at the time). Be grateful for it, and pay it forward.

I didn't downvote, but my guess is some people disagreed with this: Your adviser at the time showed great kindness to you in adding you to the paper.

Maybe some people are interpreting "pay it forward" as a suggestion to add students to papers they didn't write? (I also didn't downvote)

I think it was more that when reading between the lines, OP implied that the supervisor might have been adding random people to the different versions of the same paper to disguise any misconduct

@deee This is, very obviously, not what I have in mind. I think that the act of adding people to papers they didn't work on is clearly unethical. I do not recommend doing this. It's wrong. But it was still an act of kindness.

@WolfgangBangerth In case it wasn't clear, I wasn't trying to say I thought that's what you meant! I think I was responding to a comment about why there were downvotes, and that was my guess at why people may have been downvoting.

@Buffy has written the right answer - you can honorably just let it go.
In response to your concern about how to act

As a supervisor now advising students and advocating for the highest
standards of academic integrity ...

you might consider telling your students a short version of your story. Then they would know their advisor was once young and naive.

'you might consider telling your students a short version of your story' thanks. I think I will do that.

@whoami You should only do that in case you genuinely believe it will be helpful to them, not to alleviate your (needlessly) guilty conscience. As a general principle, sure, it's good to let students know that supervisors / instructors also make mistakes. On the other hand, it does not sound like your own mistake is something that your students need to worry about, given that they don't study "in a country with limited academic resources" and are presumably not trying to publish in an obscure language. It seems debatable whether there is any useful lesson for them in this story.

Might use American anecdotal form that can not be brought to court: "A person I know had this and that negative experience", not "My uncle got drunk in a bar and..."
Often understood as an euphemism just like "doctor, I'm asking for a friend..." but generally acceptable :)
